# Are there alternations to the recommended server chassis RM52 rack rails (RMS05-22)?

Tags: server

We have the server chassis SylverStone RM52 and need rack rails for it. Currently, rails recommended by the manufacturer (RMS05-22) are currently sold out in Germany.

Are there alternatives available?

Comment: Generally no, rails are specific to the chassis or family of chassis.